# Deploying CDH5 on virtual box cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera

So I want to create a cluster of virtual machines, with one master and 4 slave nodes, so the IP addresses will be xxx.xxx.xx.01, 02, 03, 04 and 05. I will be using 14.04 Ubuntu 64-bit. After setting up these virtual machines, do I:
- have to set static IP addresses to every machine?
- have to install CDH5 (using Cloudera Manager) on every machine, or just the one I will be using as master?
The aim of the virtual cluster is to be able to install Hadoop and Spark to run Spark jobs primarily.

Answer (score 0):

Add these hostname and IP address in /etc/hosts file.

```
[root@slave ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.111.100         master.hadoop.com
192.168.111.101        slave1.hadoop.com
192.168.111.102        slave2.hadoop.com
192.168.111.103        slave3.hadoop.com
```

Yes, you need to install CDH5 on each machine. And do the required configuration in configuration files on each machine.

You can refer this [post](http://crazyadmins.com/install-multinode-cloudera-hadoop-cluster-cdh5-4-0-manually/) for detailed installation.